# Set default/global date format in Spring MVC to ISO 8601

Tags: spring, date, datetime, spring-mvc, jodatime

I have a simple Spring Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public void search(MyDTO dto) {
    // ...
}
```

And `MyDTO`:

```
public class MyDTO {
    private DateTime date;
    public DateTime getDate() { return date; }
    public void setDate(DateTime date) { this.date = date; }
}
```

I actually can call the controller method with my local date format: `03.10.2013 01:00`, e.g. `GET http://localhost:8080/test?date=03.10.2013 01:00`

But I want application wide ISO 8601 date format, e.g.: `2007-03-01T13:00:00Z`

If I use ISO format I get the following error:

```
Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type
'org.joda.time.DateTime' for property 'date'; nested exception is
org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert
from type java.lang.String to type org.joda.time.DateTime for value
'2013-09-25T23:05:18.000+02:00'; nested exception is
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format:
"2013-09-25T23:05:18.000+02:00" is malformed at "13-09-25T23:05:18.000+02:00"
```

There must be some way to change it for `java.util.Date` and also all those Joda Date and Time containers.

I just found the `addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry)` method within `WebMvcConfigurationSupport`, but I don't really know how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working for Joda Time:

```
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {
    @Override
    public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
        JodaTimeFormatterRegistrar j = new JodaTimeFormatterRegistrar();
        j.setUseIsoFormat(true);
        j.registerFormatters(registry);
    }       
}
```

I hope there's an easier way to get this done for ALL possible Date implementations.

*Originally posted as an edit to the question by the OP, [Benjamin M](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1321564/benjamin-m)*