# Spring MVC ignores global date format?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, datetime-format

I'm trying to register a global date format in my Spring MVC application. I have followed [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.1.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#format-configuring-formatting-globaldatetimeformat). The relevant part of my Spring config file looks like this:

```
<beans:bean id="conversionService" class="org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean">
        <beans:property name="registerDefaultFormatters" value="false" />
        <beans:property name="formatters">
            <beans:set>
                <beans:bean class="org.springframework.format.number.NumberFormatAnnotationFormatterFactory" />
            </beans:set>
        </beans:property>
        <beans:property name="formatterRegistrars">
            <beans:set>
                <beans:bean class="org.springframework.format.datetime.DateFormatterRegistrar">
                    <beans:property name="formatter">
                        <beans:bean class="org.springframework.format.datetime.DateFormatter">
                            <beans:property name="pattern" value="yyyyMMdd"/>
                        </beans:bean>
                    </beans:property>
                </beans:bean>
            </beans:set>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven conversion-service="conversionService" />
```

Based on the documentation, it is my understanding that this should use the configured `DateFormatter` for all my java.util.Date properties that I write out. However, when I just write out a date (of type `java.util.Date` in my JSP file like this:

```
Availability Date: ${model.availabilityDate}
```

It still writes out the date in the default `SHORT` format, effectively ignoring my default format.

I am aware that I can register `@InitBinder` methods, or specify formats with `@DateTimeFormat`, but that's not the point. I would like to change the global default to ensure consistent output of dates in specific format, unless specified otherwise.

I found other questions on SO similar to this one, however none seem to help me solve my problem:

- [Set default/global date format in Spring MVC to ISO 8601](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19148649/set-default-global-date-format-in-spring-mvc-to-iso-8601)
- [Set date format for an input text using Spring MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10785107/set-date-format-for-an-input-text-using-spring-mvc)
- [spring mvc date format with form:input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18163404/spring-mvc-date-format-with-forminput)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the global default format only applies to marshalling of dates to and from input fields, and not when writing the date out directly using JSP.